# SQL query use of Group by functions with tricky logic

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table machine. data is present as below

```
Item         Sub_Item       qty

XYZ          ABC            100
XYZ          ABC            80
XYZ          PQR            120
DEF          KKK            100
DEF          KKK             50
DEF          LLL            120
DEF          LLL             70
QQQ          DDD            200
PQR          OOO            100
PQR          OOO             60
```

Scenario is, i need only those records,
where Item has two or more different sub_items, 
and query should return minimum of the sum(qty) of the sub_item
and it should negelect if the group by of item & sub_item return only one row.

Query result of above table should be as below.

```
Item         Sub_Item       qty

XYZ          PQR            120
DEF          KKK            150
```

It should negelect other records, as they dont meet the criteria.
Please help me with the query.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: So the item has to have more than one sub-item but you only want to display one of them?  Which one?

Comment: Where does the first row come from?  It would seem to violate your rules.

Comment: And what should happen if all the group by of sub_items for a certain item return only one row?

Comment: Scenario is, i need only those records, where Item has two or more different sub_items, and query should return minimum of the sum(qty) of the sub_item's when they grouped and it should negelect if the group by of item & sub_item return only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  y.Item,
  y.SubItem,
  y.GroupQty
from  
    ( -- Rank the items by quantity and exclude the items that only have 1 subitem.
    select
      x.Item,
      x.SubItem,
      x.GroupQty,
      dense_rank() over (partition by x.Item order by x.GroupQty) as GroupRank
    from
        ( -- Group by item and subitem. Sum quantity and count the number of subitems per item.
        select
          t.Item,
          t.Sub_Item,
          sum(t.qty) as GroupQty,
          count(distinct t.sub_item) over (partition by t.Item) as SubItemCount
        from
          YourTable t 
        group by 
          t.item,
          t.sub_item ) x
    where
      x.SubItemCount > 1) y
where
  y.GroupRank = 1 -- Return only the subitems with the lowest sum.
```

Comment: Throwing an error y.groupqty invalid identifier, please help

Comment: Okay, I forgot to select `x.GroupQty` in the inner query. After all I don't have your table (and didn't feel like creating it), so I just winged it together in Notepad. :p

Comment: Thanks man.. Its working.  Just i have to add  group by item,sub_item in the inner query.. Great help, appreciated..! :)